# java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.56.120 (port 22) from /:: (port 34178): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)

Tags: java, android, ubuntu, ssh, jsch

Estoy haciendo una aplicacion en android studio que se conecte a una maquina virtual que utiliza ubuntu desktop, usando SSH, aqui el código que uso para hacer la conexión

```
public static String executeRemoteCommand(
        String username,
        String password,
        String hostname,
        int port) throws Exception {

    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    Session session = jsch.getSession(username, hostname, 22);
    session.setPassword(password);

    // Avoid asking for key confirmation
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    session.setConfig(prop);

    session.connect();

    // SSH Channel
    ChannelExec channelssh = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    channelssh.setOutputStream(baos);

    // Execute command
    channelssh.setCommand("ls");
    channelssh.connect();
    channelssh.disconnect();

    return baos.toString();
}
```

El problema es que cuando intento mandarle un comando, "ls", me tira un error de

> connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)

no se si es algun error en el codigo, o si tengo que hacer alguna configuracion en la maquina virtual, a esta ya le instale el ssh y ya logre conectarla a otra maquina virtual que usaba ubuntu server asi que la conexion si es posible, el problema es hacerlo desde el android studio

Answer (score 0):

Antes que nada revisa que tu host, username y password son correctos, despues te hacen falta agregar los tiempos de espera que le daras al servidor para que te conteste agrega estas lineas a tu codigo:

```
session.setTimeout(10000);
```

debajo de

```
session.setConfig(prop);
```

y

```
Thread.sleep(10000);
```

debajo de

```
channelssh.connect();
```

Comment: los milisegundos que quieras darle de respuesta dependen de ti, no necesariamente deben ser 10000